# How to apply unknown query operators to a collection reference on Firebase Client

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have written a `GetCollectionAsync` method for querying collections on `Firestore`. As long as I want to get the whole collection documents, it works fine. Now I want to introduce query operators such as: `WhereEqualTo`, `WhereIn`, `WhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo`, etc

I want my method to stay generic and expose a parameter so that the caller can pass one or many query operators. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetCollectionAsync<T>(string path, /* query operators? */) 
    {
        var collectionRef = _firestoreDb.Collection(path);

        /* apply query operators to collection reference? */

        var snapshot = await collectionRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
        return snapshot.ConvertTo<T>();
    }
```

Comment: Well you can define your own enum, then use a switch statement to apply the appropriate query method. Note that you'll need the query parameter as well as another method parameter - at least for the binary query operators.

Comment: I'm not confident you could pass a delegate to pass a generic operator at this function.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/ac3276ce7d5f5181b1c419731495eb88a98537af/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.java#L400 looking at how firebase builds up its own WhereEqualTo implementation, it ends up on this whereHelper.  And it seems to look a lot like Mr. Skeet suggested, a bunch of if/else around those import com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Filter.Operator-s.

Comment: Hi @Oignon_Rouge, were you able to apply the query operators?

Comment: @FaridShumbar My approach has been to expose the CollectionReference as parameter, so that the callers can apply _outside_ all the where clauses they need

Comment: Thanks @Oignon_Rouge. Do you mind posting your workaround as an answer to make it more visible to the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by @FaridShumbar here's my workaround.

The concession I made was to split the method in two. So the caller needs first to call a `GetCollectionReference` method, apply the filters on it, and pass it to `QueryCollectionAsync` to execute the query.

Code below:

```
    public CollectionReference GetCollectionReference(string collectionPath)
    {
        return _firestoreDb.Collection(collectionPath);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryCollectionAsync<T>(Query collectionReference)
    {
        var snapshot = await collectionReference.GetSnapshotAsync();
        return snapshot.ConvertTo<T>();
    }

    // Call example
    var collectionRef = _firebaseService.GetCollectionReference(path).WhereEqualTo("image", null);
    var articles = await _firebaseService.QueryCollectionAsync<MyArticle>(collectionRef);
```